# In the space battle above Scarif, why didn't the Rebels fly around the shield gate and enter planetary surface?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In the space battle scene, the Rebels lost 2 X-wings while attempting to enter the planetary surface. Why didn't they fly around it?

Comment: For the same reasons you don't simply walk around your door, when you forgot your keys.

Comment: Vote to close it and reopen on April 1.

Answer (score 46):

They can't go 'around' the shield because the shield encompasses the entire planet.

> **“*What am I looking at?*” she asked, squinting at the ring. She made out the specks of starships descending through its center, but then a shimmer outside the ring’s edge caught her eye—the subtly distorting gleam of an energy field.**
>
> **“*There’s a planetwide defensive shield with a single main entry gate,*” Bodhi said. “*This shuttle should be equipped with an access code that allows us through.*”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_(novelization))</sup></sub>

The film's ['Ultimate Visual Guide](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rogue_One:_The_Ultimate_Visual_Guide)' factbook makes it abundantly clear that the shield has the same strength all the way round and is otherwise "impenetrable".

> Bodhi has a working familiarity with the Scarif approach — he's flown it
> over a dozen times before. However, his paltry security clearance
> means he has never set foot beyond a landing pad, several kilometers
> distant from the team's ultimate objective: the Scarif Citadel. One
> obstacle at a time is the only way to succeed in this foolhardy
> mission against overwhelming odds. **Bodhi's clearance codes get the
> shuttle past its first obstacle—an otherwise impenetrable shield
> barrier that envelops the entire planet, save for a high-altitude gate
> station.**

Comment: Since surrounding an entire planet with a shield is much more efficient than covering a single island...

Comment: @jeffronicus - The Empire had operations all over the planet. The Spire was merely the centre of said operations.

Comment: @jeffronicus Of course it is. Eg. you can't dig a tunnel under the shield.

Comment: Note that the shield doesn't have to cover the entire planet to be effective - it just has to cover **enough** of the planet to do so.  Even a local shield would prevent orbital bombardment, and would also prevent most quick raids on the base itself.  Although a shield that doesn't go all the way to the ground wouldn't prevent the movement of fighters, the gate overhead provides a _wonderful_ overwatch/early warning platform, allowing you to direct your own fighters to intercept.

Comment: @jeffronicus, you'll note the Empire is not noted for efficiency when it comes to doing things.

Answer (score 11):

It appears that the shield encased the entire planet.  The gates were the only way in while the shield was up.